# Regular Expression not working in oracle using regexp_replace, but works on regex websites?

Tags: regex, unicode, regexp-replace

im having a bit of an issue with a regex expression. Im trying to recognize patterns while excluding one set of unicode, for instance, the numbers below I wanted to capture all of them, except for the \2022. Going to one of those regex websites that allows you to see and test out what your regex is accomplishing, I am able to achieve this.

But for some reason, when I use the expression in the oracle regexp_replace function to replace these unicodes, nothing seems to be recognized. The regex pattern I am using is....

`\\[0-9A-z][0-9A-z](([1-9A-z])(?:[^2])|[0-13-9][0-9A-z])`

When I use it on the regex websites, it recognizes all 9 of the unicodes below, except the /2022 which is what I want, but for some reason its not working when I use the oracle regexp_replace function, it doesn't replace anything......anyone got any ideas?

```
\03A0
\00B0
\2002
\4004
\2022
\0BA0
\0baa
\2021
\0052
\W052
```

Comment: Oracle regex does not support non-capturing groups. Replace `(?:` with `(`.

Comment: HA, what an easy fix. Thanks man =D